# Specify which server a rails project will use

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Just wondering if this can be done. You can specify you want a new rails project to use the postgresql server ike this:

```
rails new my-new-rails-project -d postgresql
```

and that takes care of the database yaml file.

Can an option be passed in here to specify puma as the development and production server so the relevant puma.rb configuration file is created?

Something like this:

```
rails new my-new-rails-project -d postgresql -s puma
```

Answer (score 0):

By default Rails are using Webrick, but you can include different gem using Gemfile.
For example, you can use [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) (or puma, unicorn, whatever...) gem to your Gemfile and install it with bundler.

```
gem 'thin', group :development
```

When you start local server, rails will boot with custom webserver

```
rails server
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.0.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Thin web server (v1.6.1 codename Death Proof)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for server configuration in Rails. You can check using below command.

```
rails new --help
```